# Angular 2: sequence and parallel service calls

Tags: angular, rxjs

I came across a topic of sequence and parallel service calls. For sequence call, we can use flatmap/mergemap and for parallel calls, we can use forkjoin.

Below are my queries

1) what is the difference between flatmap and mergemap? Is there any specific reason to use either of it.

2) How do I add multiple sequences for 4-5 calls? what differentiates flatmap and mergemap If I use multiple subscribe?

```
this.service1.getCountry(
  .mergeMap(country => this.service1.getState(country[0]))
  .subscribe(state = > state.json());
);
```

3) forkjoin is used to join multiple parallel service calls. what if I use a method and call multiple services in that method instead of using forkjoin. Any specific reason why to go with forkJoin

Comment: it was being used in angular so i tagged it in angular

Comment: I'd suggest to add rxjs tag. It can be fully answered by a user who has no experience with Angular.

Answer (score 2):

1. `flatMap` === `mergeMap`. flatMap is simply alias to mergeMap operator. (https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/add/operator/mergeMap.ts#L5-L6) there are discussions to deprecate one alias, but so far in v5 both are available.
2. You may interested in `concurrency` param in `mergeMap` operator (https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/spec/operators/mergeMap-spec.ts#L308-L325) which subscribes multiple inner observable.
3. it depends on usecases. If supplied observable gauranteed to emit and wait for completion, forkJoin might be feasible. But if any of observable completes without emission, forkJoin will short-curcuit and completes. In opposite, mergeMap is more intended to flatten inner observable's emission into higher observable. So in case of forkJoin you'll get array of value emisssion for each innerobservables, while mergeMap will emit single values as soon as each inner observable emits.

Comment: I am not clear with second point. can you please help me with adding third service call in my above example. First service call i get country, second i get state. third i want to call city. can you please add it to my code?